# Problems using FTP, Steam, and other non-browser web services on public password protected wi-fi on MacOS

Tags: network, wifi, macos

I currently have to use a wi-fi service which is public (doesn't have a WPA password), but which uses a username and password sign in via browser (provided by SOPHOS UTM). I access this on a Mac with the latest macOS.

While I can connect to the internet with all browsers and some other applications like Spotify and Skype, I cannot use FTP, SQL or VPN clients, and I also can't use Steam, battle.net or TeamSpeak. For all of the latter, the connection always times out and I cannot connect to any of those services.

The odd thing is that in any other wi-fi network, all of those applications work perfectly fine on my computer. I've already contacted the wi-fi network's support, but they're just as baffled as me and claim that all other users on the network can use those applications without problems.

I've already tried pretty much anything I could think of (system reboot, system update, logging on as a different user, turning off all kinds of firewalls, etc), but nothing helped.

Does anyone have an idea why some applications can connect to the internet perfectly fine on macOS, while others cannot?

Comment: Most of those apps try to contact you back on another port (e.g. ftp) or use other ports e.g. Steam so I suspect there is a firewall between the wifi and the internet

Comment: As mentioned above, the support told me that the ports are all open and that other users can use those services fine. That's why I suspect it might be something macOS related.

Comment: First thing I'd check is the Mac's firewall, just in case, but it's rather doubtful on a Sophos UTM that "all ports are open", that's the equivalent of not bothering with it at all. They may have all output ports open, i.e. a rule that anything generated within the internal network is allowed out, but no-one is ever going to have all input ports open. Sophos UTM isn't an application-based firewall like you'd find on a standard home PC. Best course of action - with the help of IT - would be for them to watch the firewall's Live Log as you try & see what is rejected.

Comment: I've tried it with the Mac's firewall off, still nothing :( And like I said, it works perfectly fine on other networks. I've also tried live monitoring with the support, but they couldn't see anything that was being blocked there...

Comment: OK, new test [need to do this quickly as it's not very safe to leave open.] Get them to set up a new rule "Any to Any using any service" & set it to the top of the list [this effectively bypasses the firewall in both directions]. Do a quick test, check results, switch the rule off again. If you succeed with that rule in place, then it's the UTM firewall settings. If not, then you need to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Together with support, I found the solution. All other protocols worked on LAN but not on wi-fi, and there was just a rudimentary setting which didn't allow the other protocols on wi-fi (unfortunately I don't know the details, as it was the support who solved it, not me).